# Using combinations in Linear Regressions

Tags: python, combinations, linear-regression, python-itertools, statsmodels

I am using statsmodels for linear regressions and itertools to find the combinations

I have a CSV file with headers several and different number values similar to below

A | B | C

1 | 1.1 | 0.95

2 | 2.1 | 1.95

3 | 3.1 | 2.95

I am trying to use combinations to find the possible R^2 values when using 1, 2, ... X columns with statsmodels

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
from pandas import DataFrame
from itertools import combinations 
import csv

df = pd.read_csv("All_Holes_No_B.csv")
Stats = ["A","B",..."X"]
for i in range(1, len(Stats)+1):
    for c in combinations(Stats,i):
        X= df[[c]] 
        y = df["K"] 
        model = sm.OLS(y, X).fit()
        predictions = model.predict(X)
        print(model.rsquared)
```

I keep getting an error code that says

KeyError: "None of [Index([('A',)], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"

When I hard code in the values to use `X=df[["A","B"..."X"]]` it works perfectly. Can I get a hand so I don't have to do 500+ runs manually.

-edit-

Here's the whole error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\00MasterProject\Loop_Regression.py", line 29, in <module>
    X= df[[list(z)]]
  File "C:\...\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2986, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.loc._convert_to_indexer(key, axis=1, raise_missing=True)
  File "C:\...\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1285, in _convert_to_indexer
    return self._get_listlike_indexer(obj, axis, **kwargs)[1]
  File "C:\...\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1092, in _get_listlike_indexer
    keyarr, indexer, o._get_axis_number(axis), raise_missing=raise_missing
  File "C:\...\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1177, in _validate_read_indexer
    key=key, axis=self.obj._get_axis_name(axis)
KeyError: "None of [Index([('A', 'B')], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"
```

Comment: add the location of the exception. This might be a pandas error when you use `X= df[[c]] `. As a guess, this might need `df[list(c)]` or your `df` is not correct.

Comment: Thanks Josef. That was 90% of my problem. I also accidentally put double brackets ` X= df[[list(z)]]` After I removed the extra set of brackets that fixed the problem so now I have ` X= df[list(z)]` and the problem is fixed. Thanks again